# How do you get data from a variable into a JSON object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I am very new to JSON. I am writing a program in JavaScript and have tried looking for a simple answer. I guess I don’t know how to ask it right.

I want the user to input their information and it will be added into a JSON object. But I cannot get JSON to accept the value.
Let's assume that `userName="Bob"`.

```
const userJSON=`{
    "playerName": userName
}`;
```

I want `userJSON` to be `"playerName": "Bob"`
It keeps giving me an error saying that `userName` is not valid JSON.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I can get it to parse out information if it is `"playerName":"Bob"` but this is part of a game that people need to be able to add their own usernames.

Comment: `userName is not valid JSON` that's not possible. `userName` is a variable .... `let userName="Bob"; `const userJSON = {"playerName": userName}` will never throw a JSON error, since there's absolutely no JSON involved in that code (just because you've named a variable `userJSON` doesn't make it JSON ... it's still an object

Comment: ahh ^^ didn't see the template string  before the question was edited :p

Answer (score 1):

You are using template strings so you need to add the variable using `${}` AND quotes around string variables like this

```
const userJSON = `{ "playerName": "${userName}" }`;
```

OR create the object and stringify it (makes more sense)

```
const userOBJ = { "playerName": userName }; 
const userJSON = JSON.stringify(userOBJ);
```